# How can I selectively change custom split normals in python

Tags: python, normals

Using 2.80. I have a solution how to get the wanted loops via the bmesh faces. I can set all split normals at ones with normals_split_custom_set. But for this to work I need to read the old normals so that they will go unchanged when I overwrite them. How can I do this? Is there a better way?